# Prove that if $A\cap B = \emptyset$, then $P(A\cup B) \sim P(A)\times P(B)$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Prove that if $A\cap B = \emptyset$, then $P(A\cup B) \sim P(A)\times P(B)$.

I have no idea on how to proceed on this proof.
A hint will be preferable than a solution.

$P(X)$ is the power set of $X$ and "$\sim$"  means "equipotent/equivalent to"

Also I want to know what's the significance of $A\cap B = \emptyset$.

This is a question from my assignment from elementary set theory class.

I have no idea where this question is from.

I have done some similar questions but I have specific difficulty in this one.

Comment: It might be helpful to remind yourself, what the definition of the power set is and what you actually want to prove (spelling out what it means to be "equivalent").

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: I have some idea of what power set and equipotency is. But I need to find a bijection between them to prove this result(or use Bernstein theorem). How do I do that ?

Comment: What are you studying?
What text is this drawn from, if any? If not, how did the question arise?
What kind of approaches (to similar problems) are you familiar with?
Is this question something you think should be able to answer? Why or why not?

Comment: Edited the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** A subset of $A \cup B$ can be broken up as the union of a subset of $A$ with a subset of $B$. Prove that if $A$ and $B$ are disjoint, then there is one and only one way of doing this.

**Bigger hint:** Hover your cursor over the box below.

> There is a function $\mathcal{P}(A) \times \mathcal{P}(B) \to \mathcal{P}(A \cup B)$ given by $(U, V) \mapsto U \cup V$. This function is always surjective, even if $A$ and $B$ are not disjoint. Prove that if $A \cap B = \varnothing$, then this function is also injective.